# Recovering Windows 11

Tags: linux, boot, windows-11, dualboot

I messed up Windows 11 when I resized my linux partition in gparted, after this when I tried to boot Win 11 from the grub menu, I was getting two lines of error about gpt and windows manager, etc.

Searching for solutions led me to few stack exchange pages, where the users suggested, I install mbr, lilo and fix the Windows problem, when I ran this on the system drive lilo gave me an error, so I installed in on the drive like sda, this completely eliminated the Windows boot entry and it is directly booting into linux. As this didn't work, I ran mbr on the partition on which Win 11 was installed which is sda3, after doing this, gparted is showing it's file system as unknown, the same file system information is shown for Microsoft reserved partition too.

EFI system partition is fine it shows fat32.

How can I get it back to boot, and is it possible to recover Windows partition from unknown filesysten to ntfs, so that I can use Win 11?

Comment: It sounds like you permanently deleted your partition. Windows 11 cannot be installed on a disk formatted as MBR, it only supports GPT.

Answer (score 2):

GPT and MBR are mutually exclusive.
They apply to entire disks, not partitions.

lilo is a bootloader, not often used. Especially since you already had grub (which is a bootloader)

Would need to know the source of the

> about gpt and windows manager, etc.

error. grub, or windows?

You've broken your EFI. And now potentially installed a boot loader and MBR to your windows partition (??)

You need to fix that. At this point I'd re-image the drive with the backup you made before f*king with it. You know, when gparted warned you that it could cause loss of data.

Alternatively you're now looking at partition recovery tools. `testdisk` would do, but ahh, probably image the whole drive and work on the image, before overwriting the partition table, again.